# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, nullreferenceexception

I have a class Cell:

```
public class Cell
{
    public enum cellState
    {
        WATER,
        SCAN,
        SHIPUNIT,
        SHOT,
        HIT
    }

    public Cell()
    {
        currentCell = cellState.WATER;
        MessageBox.Show(currentCell.ToString());
    }

    public cellState currentCell { get; set; }
}
```

I then try to use it in the following class:

```
public class NietzscheBattleshipsGameModel
{
    private byte MAXCOL = 10;
    private byte MAXROW = 10;

    public Cell[,] HomeArray;

    private Cell[,] AwayArray;

    public NietzscheBattleshipsGameModel()
    {
        HomeArray = new Cell [MAXCOL, MAXROW];

        AwayArray = new Cell [MAXCOL, MAXROW];
    }


    public string alphaCoords(Int32 x)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > 9)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        char alphaChar = (char)('A' + x);

        return alphaChar.ToString();
    }

    public void test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {

                // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                MessageBox.Show(HomeArray[i,j].currentCell.ToString());
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I end up with the Object reference not set to an instance of an object (between the ///// in the above code..

I have tried creating a single instance of Cell and it works fine.

Comment: To add to the given answers: If you declare a `public struct Cell` instead of a `class`, then you don't have to `new()` them up individually in those loops, because a `struct` is a ValueType and thus is always initialized with the default values of its members.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you instantiate an array, the items in the array receive the default value for that type. Thus for

```
T[] array = new T[length];
```

it is the case that for every `i` with `0 <= i < length` we have `array[i] = default(T)`. Thus, for reference types `array[i]` will be `null`. This is why you are seeing the `NullReferenceException`. In your case `Cell` is a reference type so since you have

```
HomeArray = new Cell [MAXCOL, MAXROW];
```

and all you have done is establish an array of references to `Cell`s but you never assigned those references to instances of `Cell`. That is, you told the compiler "give me an array that can hold references to `Cell`s" but you did not tell the compiler "give me an array that can hold references to `Cell`s and assign each of those references to a new instance of `Cell`." Thus, the compiler will set the initial value of those references to `null`. Therefore you need to initialize the `HomeArray`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXCOL; i++)  { 
    for (int j = 0; j < MAXROW; j++)  { 
        HomeArray[i, j] = new Cell();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize the Cells in your arrays.

```
public NietzscheBattleshipsGameModel()
{
    HomeArray = new Cell[MAXCOL, MAXROW];
    AwayArray = new Cell[MAXCOL, MAXROW];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXCOL; j++)
        {
            HomeArray[i,j] = new Cell();
            AwayArray[i,j] = new Cell();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ok i got it now. i thought the declaration of it would be enough. thanks to all for your good advise.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are initialised to be empty - the Null reference is because `HomeArray[i,j]` is null, not because `HomeArray[i,j].currentCell` is null.

*UPDATE:* If you have a statement where a couple of different things could be null, then I generally split that up into multiple lines to make it easier to tell what is null.

For example, in your case:

```
MessageBox.Show(HomeArray[i,j].currentCell.ToString());
```

Either `HomeArray[i,j]` or `HomeArray[i,j].currentCell` could potentially be null and trigger a NullReferenceException - there is no way to tell which it was from the exception.  If you split that statement up however:

```
Cell cell = HomeArray[i,j].currentCell;
MessageBox.Show(cell.ToString());
```

In this case if `HomeArray[i,j]` is null then you get your NullReferenceException on the first, line whereas if `cell` is null you get it on the second line.

Comment: i got the part: arrays are initialised to be empty. then i do not understand the rest of it sorry. please be kind enough to inform me further.

Comment: @ikurtz - I've tweaked my answer a little bit, is it any clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because you are not assigning an instance of Cell to any of the slots of your matrices.